# send and receive JSON over sockets in server and client application in C

Tags: c, json, sockets

> I want to send the data in JSON over sockets in a server-client
>   application written in C.
>
> I am using [json-c / libjson](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/json-c-libjson-tutorial/) library for handling JSON data in C
>   application.

By working on some of the tutorials I am able to create JSON object and able to parse it successfully.

Now I want to use the JSON data format for the communication of server-client.

Here is part of my server and client code

**server.c**

```
int main()
{
   int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;    //related with the server
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

   //json_object * jobj;
   uint8_t buf[158], i;

   memset(&buf, '0', sizeof(buf));
   listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8888); 

   bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   printf("binding\n");

   listen(listenfd, 5);
   printf("listening\n");
   connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

   printf("Reading from client\n");

   while ( (read(connfd, buf, 157)) > 0 )
   {
      for ( i = 0; i < 157; i++ )
         //printf("%s\n", json_object_to_json_string(jobj));
         //json_parse(jobj);
         printf("%d\n", buf[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**client.c**

```
int main()
{ 
    char* str;
    int fd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in demoserverAddr;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Error : Could not create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        demoserverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        demoserverAddr.sin_port = htons(8888);
        demoserverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        memset(demoserverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(demoserverAddr.sin_zero));
    }

    if (connect(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&demoserverAddr, sizeof(demoserverAddr)) < 0)
    {
         printf("ERROR connecting to server\n");
         return 1;
    }

    /*Creating a json object*/
    json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();

    /*Creating a json string*/
    json_object *jstring = json_object_new_string("Joys of Programming");

    /*Creating a json integer*/
    json_object *jint = json_object_new_int(10);

    /*Creating a json boolean*/
    json_object *jboolean = json_object_new_boolean(1);

    /*Creating a json double*/
    json_object *jdouble = json_object_new_double(2.14);

    /*Creating a json array*/
    json_object *jarray = json_object_new_array();

    /*Creating json strings*/
    json_object *jstring1 = json_object_new_string("c");
    json_object *jstring2 = json_object_new_string("c++");
    json_object *jstring3 = json_object_new_string("php");

    /*Adding the above created json strings to the array*/
    json_object_array_add(jarray,jstring1);
    json_object_array_add(jarray,jstring2);
    json_object_array_add(jarray,jstring3);

    /*Form the json object*/
    /*Each of these is like a key value pair*/
    json_object_object_add(jobj,"Site Name", jstring);
    json_object_object_add(jobj,"Technical blog", jboolean);
    json_object_object_add(jobj,"Average posts per day", jdouble);
    json_object_object_add(jobj,"Number of posts", jint);
    json_object_object_add(jobj,"Categories", jarray);

    printf("Size of JSON object- %lu\n", sizeof(jobj));
    printf("Size of JSON_TO_STRING- %lu,\n %s\n", sizeof(json_object_to_json_string(jobj)), json_object_to_json_string(jobj));

    //printf("Size of string- %lu\n", sizeof(json_object_to_json_string(jobj)));
    write(fd, json_object_to_json_string(jobj), 157);

    printf("Written data\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to send the json_object jobj from client to server.
How to do this?

Some things that I tried:

1. When I use `write(fd, jobj, sizeof(jobj))`, the client sends only 8 bytes and other characters are null when I receive data on server.
2. I am only able to send complete json_object jobj when I use `write(fd, json_object_to_json_string(jobj), 157)` where 157 is the total number of characters in that jobj object.
3. On server side if I use `read(connfd, jobj, sizeof(jobj))` then I only able to receive 8 bytes (on client side I am using `write(fd, jobj, sizeof(jobj))`).
4. If I use the above server.c, I am able to receive complete JSON object (if I already know the number of characters in that object). But it is in raw format (receiving byte by byte).

How to send the complete json_object jobj from client side?

And how to receive the complete json_object jobj on server side?

Comment: write(fd, jobj, sizeof(jobj))  -> write(fd, jobj, sizeof(*jobj))

Comment: @kkk thanks for the reply. It is giving an error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type write(fd, jobj, sizeof(*jobj));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) jobj is a **pointer**, so when you use

```
write(fd, jobj, sizeof(jobj))
```

you're writing a **pointer** to that object, not that object.

3) Same as before.

Maybe you should try sending it with something like

```
if (write(fd, jobj, sizeof(*jobj)) == -1)
    /* error handler /*
```

On the receive side, you should do a for loop, like

```
for (;;)
{
    r = read(fd, jobj, SIZE);

    if (r == -1)
        /*error handler*/
    if (r == 0)
        break;
}
```

if you know the maximum SIZE of the json, or combine *malloc()* and *realloc()* otherwise

EDIT:

I did this, and now it works fine.

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    /* all previous code until
    printf("Size of string- %lu\n", sizeof(json_object_to_json_string(jobj)))*/

    char temp_buff[MAX_SIZE];

    if (strcpy(temp_buff, json_object_to_json_string(jobj)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("strcpy");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (write(fd, temp_buff, strlen(temp_buff)) == -1)
    {
        perror("write");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Written data\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    /* all previous code until
    printf("Reading from client\n"); */

    ssize_t r;

    char buff[MAX_SIZE];

    for (;;)
    {
        r = read(connfd, buff, MAX_SIZE);

        if (r == -1)
        {
            perror("read");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (r == 0)
            break;

        printf("READ: %s\n", buff);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

MAX_SIZE is a macro that specifies the maximum buffer length, set it as you wish.
Please next time paste ALL your code (including the `#include ...`) and indent it properly.

Comment: its giving error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type write(fd, jobj, sizeof(*jobj));

Comment: It's because he doesn't know the **struct json_object**.
You can:
1) find it in the library and paste it into your file .c
2) use the *json_object_to_json_string()* function. 

I think that the 2) is more accurate, given the fact that is a library function written for that purpose.

Comment: thanks for the reply. printf("Size of JSON_TO_STRING- %lu\n ", sizeof(*json_object_to_json_string(jobj)) gives output as Size of JSON_TO_STRING- 1; I dont know if it is correct and I used write(fd, json_object_to_json_string(jobj), sizeof(*json_object_to_json_string(jobj))); to write the JSON object. On server I am assuming the maximum size is 200 bytes and using r = read(connfd, jobj, 200); But a.out crashes with Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: @ igng thanks for the reply I did not check it yet but as I can see you are suggesting to send byte by byte from client and also receive on server side as byte by byte; Is it possible to receive data as JSON object?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, is exactly what I'm doing above. The JSON is put into a string and then passed through the socket. If **client.c** writes *{ "Site Name": "Joys of Programming", "Technical blog": true, "Average posts per day": 2.140000, "Number of posts": 10, "Categories": [ "c", "c++", "php" ] }*, then **server.c** will read *{ "Site Name": "Joys of Programming", "Technical blog": true, "Average posts per day": 2.140000, "Number of posts": 10, "Categories": [ "c", "c++", "php" ] }*

Comment: @ igng Thanks for the help. Its working fine. Sorry for the code will definitely consider ur suggestions next time onwards

Comment: Maybe you're allocating less space than required for write/read (e.g. your JSON's length is 210 bytes and you're allocating 200 bytes) or something like that.

Comment: Hi @igng thanks for the reply. I don't think thats the issue coz my buffer is quite large than the JSON's length

Answer (score 1):

To use TCP socket messages you have the client and server learn how to interpret the messages.

HTTP, for example, uses the 2 characters \r\n as end of message
Another alternative option is to send the size of the message before the message.

Here's a solution that does that using the JSON Jansson library.
It adds the size as a sequence of characters (e.g "123", is later parsed as integer 123), adding the character "#" as end of size header then the JSON text representation of the JSON object (as defined by the Jansson library)

```
size_t socket_t::write(json_t *json)
{
  char *buf_json = NULL;
  std::string buf_send;
  size_t size_json;

  //get char* from json_t
  buf_json = json_dumps(json, JSON_PRESERVE_ORDER);
  size_json = strlen(buf_json);
  //construct send buffer, adding a header with size in bytes of JSON and # terminator
  buf_send = std::to_string(static_cast<long long unsigned int>(size_json));
  buf_send += "#";
  buf_send += std::string(buf_json);

  this->write(buf_send.data(), buf_send.size());

  free(buf_json);
  return buf_send.size();
}
```

The reading is done with

```
json_t * socket_t::read()
{
  int recv_size; // size in bytes received or -1 on error 
  const int size_buf = 20;
  char buf[size_buf];

  //peek header
  if ((recv_size = recv(m_socket, buf, size_buf, MSG_PEEK)) == -1)
  {
    std::cout << "recv error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }

  //get size of JSON message
  std::string str(buf);
  size_t pos = str.find("#");
  std::string str_header(str.substr(0, pos));

  //parse header
  if ((recv_size = recv(m_socket, buf, str_header.size() + 1, 0)) == -1)
  {
    std::cout << "recv error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }

  //sanity check
  buf[recv_size - 1] = '\0';
  assert(str_header.compare(buf) == 0);

  size_t size_json = static_cast<size_t>(std::stoull(str_header));
  std::string str_buf = read_all(size_json);
  //terminate buffer with size
  std::string str_json = str_buf.substr(0, size_json);

  //construct JSON
  json_error_t *err = NULL;
  json_t *json = json_loadb(str_json.data(), str_json.size(), JSON_PRESERVE_ORDER, err);
  return json;
}
```

This is implemented in

https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_netsockets