# Receive raw JSON string through TCP C++

Tags: c++, json, tcp

So I need to receive a raw JSON string through a TCP connection.
I programmed a console application to receive the string. I tested the connection with telnet by sending text and it works fine. But when someone is sending me raw JSON strings I do not seem to receive anything. Is this because of the recv function?

Here is my code for receiving:

```
if ((new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        // Receive until the peer closes the connection
        do {
            iResult = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if (iResult > 0) {
                string input(recvbuf,iResult);
                cout << input;
                log << input;
            }
            else if (iResult == 0)
                printf("Connection closed\n");
            else
                printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

        } while (iResult > 0);
    }
```

I convert the input (recvbuf) to a string and print it to my console and to a log file. But when I use telnet it works fine, but if someone sends me raw JSON strings I seem to get no data. Is this a problem on my side (recv the wrong function or something?) or theirs? I tried using the read function but it creates a Assertion failed error.

[image: error]

Comment: *but it creates a Assertion failed error.*  -- Let's see what is being asserted by posting the error.

Comment: Can you use wireshark to see the difference of what telnet sends and what the "raw json client" sends?

Comment: "Raw JSON strings"? Isn't that a regular (printable) character sequence with a quotation mark at each end? (JSON is just text, no?)

Comment: Which line asserts? How about something that actually compiles? How about using a fake recv function to test your reading code??

Comment: I added the error, this error only happens when using read (I saw some people use read instead of recv, I thought it might be a solution). When I use recv it compiles and works fine if I test it myself. But someone else is trying to send me raw JSON strings. Unfortunately I cannot see the difference right now because I they have to connect to me and they are on the other side of the world. So I have no direct control over when they will send the data. I was just trying to see if I made a mistake and maybe someone could point me at the problem. Maybe they are doing something wrong with sending.

Comment: @paulm the line after do { assert when I use read instead of recv, I thought it might be a solution because I saw some forum posts about json and sockets which where using read and not recv

Comment: @molbdnilo Thats what I thought, so yesterday I opened the connection and because we have a lot of time difference I hoped this morning I would see the json strings that they send. But apart from successful connections, I didn't receive anything, so I assumed i did something wrong. But I try to solve it before I have to leave the office so in the evening (their morning) they can try again. I can ask them what could be wrong, but I wont have an answer until tomorrow morning, thats why I try it here

Comment: @stefaanv I opened wireshark and found how I can catch anything that is send on the port I use for the connection. But I can't really see anything they send until tomorrow morning. Then I will be able to compare it.

Comment: Strange - the error message looks like you have an invalid socket. You're not clobbering `new_socket` with a buffer overrun or closing it in another thread or something like that?

Comment: @molbdnilo I just replaced recv with read and then ran everything the exact same way. read does always show that assertion failed and recv never. Maybe read is not compatible with winsock? I use it like this iResult = _read(new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen);

Comment: I don't think you can pass a socket handle to _read

Comment: @paulm I tried it because I read it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667109/send-and-receive-json-over-sockets-in-server-and-client-application-in-c that is why I tried that, but you might be right about that